# Вывод миниатюр категорий woocommerce в меню

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Добрый день. Возник вопрос. На сайте есть меню - категории товаров (каталог продукции). Вывод производится через стандартное wp_nav_menu(). 
[image: пример меню]

Проблема заключается в том, что нужно добавить миниатюру для каждой родительской категории. В данном случае на картинке нужно добавить миниатюру, которая есть в настройках категорий товаров Woocommerce, к слову Бочки. Возможно ли это как-то сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создать новый класс для построения меню Walker_Nav_Menu и использовать его в выводе через функцию wp_nav_menu():

```
<?php

// Класс для построения меню
class woocommerce_menu_with_thumbnails_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $item->object_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        $output .= '<li><img src="'.$thumbnail_url.'" alt="" /> <a href="'.$item->url.'">'.$item->title.'</a></li>';
    }
}

$args = array(
    'menu' => '123', // ID, slug или название меню
    'echo' => true,
    'fallback_cb' => false,
    'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
    'walker' => new woocommerce_menu_with_thumbnails_walker(),
);

wp_nav_menu( $args );

?>
```

Подробнее про класс Walker можно почитать в официальной документации: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker

Comment: Класс ради одного метода?

Comment: Добро пожаловать в Wordpress.